# Асинхронные сокеты С#

Tags: c#, сокет

Доброе время суток.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться и найти ошибку в коде Клиента для асинхронного I/O.
При компиляции клиента приложение выводит на экран информацию и сразу же закрывается, а при открытии исполняемого файла выводит ошибку о неизвестном хосте (аналогично и на сервере), хотя на сервере отображается, что подключение было произведено.

```
class Server
{
    private IPEndPoint ip;
    private Socket socket;
    private int max_conn = 2;
    private const int port = 11000;
    private ManualResetEvent acceptEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public Server()
    {
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve("localhost");
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        this.ip = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);
        this.socket = new Socket(this.ip.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        this.Init();
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        this.socket.Bind(this.ip);
        this.socket.Listen(this.max_conn);
        this.StartListening();
    }

    private void StartListening()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Server starting...");
        while (true)
        {
            acceptEvent.Reset();
            this.socket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallBack), this.socket);
            acceptEvent.WaitOne();
        }
    }

    private void AcceptCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Socket socket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket accept_socket = socket.EndAccept(ar);
        acceptEvent.Set();
        Console.WriteLine("A new connection. IP:port = " + accept_socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Server server = new Server();
    }
}
```

}

```
    class Client
    {
    private IPEndPoint ip;
    private Socket client_socket;
    private const int port = 11000;

    public Client()
    {
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve("localhost");
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        this.ip = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);
        this.client_socket = new Socket(this.ip.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        this.Connect();
        this.Disconnect();
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        this.client_socket.BeginConnect(this.ip, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallBack), this.client_socket);
    }

    private void ConnectCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        this.client_socket.EndConnect(ar);
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        this.client_socket.BeginDisconnect(false, new AsyncCallback(DisconnectCallBack), this.client_socket);
    }
    private void DisconnectCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Socket handler = ar.AsyncState as Socket;
        handler.EndDisconnect(ar);
        Console.WriteLine("Connection closed");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Client server = new Client();
    }
}
```

Comment: > При компиляции клиента приложение выводит на экран информацию и сразу же закрывается

Простите?

Comment: @VladD, консоль клиента закрывается сразу после запуска.

Comment: @wao138: Ну вы же написали «при компиляции», а не «при запуске». Это и было непонятно.

Answer (score 1):

А что вы ожидали, если у Вас в методе Main по строчке кода:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Client client = new Client();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Server server = new Server();
}
```

Comment: Так а что добавить нужно?

Comment: Ну как минимум, у сервера вызвать server.StartListening(), а у клиента client.Connect()

Comment: @sp7, оно вообще-то вызывается.

Comment: @wao138, не заметил. А почему у вас в конструкторе клиента вызывается метод Connect(), а сразу за ним Disconnect() ? Уберите Connect() и Disconnect() из конструктора и попробуйте вызывать их по мере необходимости.

Comment: По крайней мере `Disconnect()` там точно лишний.